# Getting unexpected result when combining [[no_unique_address]] with empty base class inheritance

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider [following](https://godbolt.org/z/oGbYhWqc7):

```
struct Base {};

struct Empty {};

struct X : Base {
  int i;
  [[no_unique_address]] Empty e;
};

static_assert(sizeof(X) == 4);
```

The `X` inherits the empty `Base` and gains [EBO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo), and since its member `e` also uses `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute, this makes the size of `X` only the size of the `int`.

But when I use `X` as a member variable of another struct `Y` that inherits an empty `Base`, the size of `Y` suddenly becomes `8`:

```
struct Y : Base {
  X x;
  [[no_unique_address]] Empty e;
};

static_assert(sizeof(Y) == 8);
```

Did `Y` violate the standard and make EBO banned? Or does this just depend on the implementation of the compiler vendor?

Comment: Two `Empty` class cannot share the same address. Quality of Implementation to place second `e` in available byte of `i` (which can have `sizeof(int)` `Empty` classes).

Comment: @Jarod42 So you mean that even if I create different `Empty` classes, the `Y`'s two `Base` classes cannot share the same address so that its size is [still](https://godbolt.org/z/5MqsP76Mv) `8`?

Comment: 2 distinct objects should have different addresses, So EBO cannot apply to `Base`. And I doubt it is allowed to place Base inside free space in `X` as it is the case for `[[no_unique_address]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoted directly from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo):

> Empty base optimization is prohibited if one of the empty base classes
> is also the type or the base of the type of the first non-static data
> member, since the two base subobjects of the same type are required to
> have different addresses within the object representation of the most
> derived type.

Comment: `e` is not the **first** member or base class of `Y`. `Empty` "just" uses `[[no_unique_address]]`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I mean `Base`---the empty base, is the base of `X`---the type of the first non-static data member `x`.

Comment: Oups, I miss there are 2 `Base` and focusses on `Empty` :/. ..

Comment: @康桓瑋 Because the address of the base object of `e` should still be different from that of the base object of an `Y` object. If EBO happens, since `e` has no unique address, the two bases will share the same address.